# Can lawful permanent residents in the United States apply to the 10-year, multiple-entry Chinese L (tourist) visa?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, us-permanent-residents

Can [lawful permanent residents in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawful_permanent_residents_(United_States)) apply to the [10-year, multiple-entry Chinese L (tourist) visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=867954431#Visa_facilitation_agreements)?

From what I can see:

- http://visa.ywpw.com/ChineseVisa/nonUSCitizen_en.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181113035626/http://visa.ywpw.com/ChineseVisa/nonUSCitizen_en.html)) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=867954431#Visa_facilitation_agreements) do not mention it
- https://www.saporedicina.com/english/chinese-visa-application/([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181113035759/https://www.saporedicina.com/english/chinese-visa-application/)) says it's possible: "U.S. citizens may be eligible for a 10-year multiple entry Visa. [...] You can apply for this visa even if you don’t have an American passport but are still a resident of the United States."
- http://www.chinaconsulatesf.org/eng/lszj/zgqz/t751633.htm  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/http://www.chinaconsulatesf.org/eng/lszj/zgqz/t751633.htm)): "U.S. permanent resident card holders who have lived overseas for at least one year can apply for a multiple-entry permit valid for 2 years." but I'm not sure what they mean by overseas, that could be living in Hong Kong given the context.

So it's quite unclear to me what the answer is.

I am interested in the case of French citizens if that matters. French citizens may only apply to a one-entry or two-entry Chinese L (tourist) visa (up to 30 days per entry), unless perhaps if they are lawful permanent residents in the United States.

Answer (score 2):

No, the 10 Year Multi-Entry Visa is not available to you.

While you are a US Permanent Resident, you are still applying as a French Citizen using that Passport.  You only options are Visas available for French Passports.

The 2 Year Visa you mention is only available to Chinese Citizens who are US Permanent Residents and is valid only for Hong Kong.